# custom pagination in asp.net page index not taking correct index

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I created custom pagination in asp.net. I have 100 pages and I don't want that 100 page buttons in one page. so i created like this << 1 2 3 4 5 ... >>. If we click on 5th button the links will be << 6 7 8 9 10 ... >>

The problem I'm facing is that button is not taking correct index.when page is loaded for first time first page data is displayed. Then when I click button 2 its also fine, if I click button 3 again it is taking index 1, not index 3.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      int pageIndex = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
      this.GetCustomersPageWise(pageIndex);
  }
```

anybody knows the solution for this problem?

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged SQL unless the problem is with a procedure then it is probably unnecessary. Where are you setting the indexes initially? In the properties? Form load? I think we need more code here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the code related to Linkbutton(aspx/ascx). I could only guess that you have incorrect CommandArgument, while the CommandText could display correctly in the view. 
Please have a look at the below example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx